# Set Redis ElastiCache eviction policy via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elasticache

I want to set my Redis cluster on AWS ElastiCache to the [LRU eviction mode](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache). The version of my Redis cluster is 5.0.6.

I have looked through the documentation of the Terraform [`aws_elasticache_replication_group` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_replication_group) but I cannot find any attribute to set eviction policy. As far as I know the default policy is no eviction.

How can I change the eviction policy in Terraform?

Answer (score 3):

ElastiCache configuration is done via the [`aws_elasticache_parameter_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_parameter_group) resource. You can then specify any of the [parameters that are allowed by ElastiCache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Redis.html).

Looking at the available parameters you would want to set the `maxmemory-policy` but it's worth noting that the default isn't to not evict (`noeviction`) and instead defaults to `volatile-lru` in all current versions of Redis ElastiCache which might be what you need anyway. If instead you wanted to use `allkeys-lru` then you would do something like the following:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_parameter_group" "this" {
  name   = "cache-params"
  family = "redis5.0"

  parameter {
    name  = "maxmemory-policy"
    value = "allkeys-lru"
  }
}
```